# Query like '%t%' is case insensitive or not? why use it twice shows different result?

Tags: sql

I'm confusing about below two queries, why **'emplastname like '%t%'** appears in main query can filter the record of 'Tang'? Does it mean that using it twice can filter uppercase?  Command '%t%' is case insensitive, isn't it?

First query:

```
SELECT e.empno, e.emplastname, e.empphone, e.empcommrate 
FROM employee e 
WHERE e.empcommrate = 
     (               SELECT max(empcommrate) 
                     FROM employee 
                     WHERE emplastname like '%t%');

empno    |   emplastname    |   empphone    |  empcommrate
E8843211    Tang             (303) 556-4321     0.040
E9345771    White            (303) 221-4453     0.040
```

Second query:

```
SELECT e.empno, e.emplastname, e.empphone, e.empcommrate 
    FROM employee e 
    WHERE e.emplastname like '%t%'
    AND   e.empcommrate = 
           (             SELECT max(empcommrate) 
                         FROM employee 
                         WHERE emplastname like '%t%');

    empno    |   emplastname    |   empphone    |  empcommrate
    E9345771    White            (303) 221-4453     0.040
```

Comment: WW explained the difference between your two queries. Nvertheless: the case sensitivity of such a query depends on the DBMS product (and possibly its configuration).

Answer (score 4):

You first query says:

> Return all employees who have `empcommrate` equal to the maximum
>   `empcommrate` of any employee with "t" in their name.

Your second query says:

> Return all employees who have "t" in their name, and who have
>   `empcommrate` equals to the maximum `empcommrate` of any employee with
>   "t" in their name.

So they are two different queries.  To see the difference more clearly, consider these queries:

```
SELECT e.empno, e.emplastname, e.empphone, e.empcommrate 
FROM employee e 
WHERE e.empcommrate = 0.040;
```

And:

```
SELECT e.empno, e.emplastname, e.empphone, e.empcommrate 
    FROM employee e 
    WHERE e.emplastname like '%t%'
    AND   e.empcommrate = 0.040;
```

In these queries I've replaced the subselect with the value returned by that subselect.  You can see that like '%t%' in the subselect does not limit the employees ultimately returned.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: The inner query fetches value of 0.040 and then it lists all employees with empcommrate=0.040
Case 2: Inner query fetched 0.040 as earlier, but now you have placed an additional and conditions which will list only those employees which have "t" (in lower case) in their last name. Note String comparisons are case sensitive by default in Oracle.